# How to create clang plugin on windows

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a dynamic clang plugin on windows.
Tried to use both msvc and clang itself as compilers, different linkers, but still the same problem appears, the linker swears at missing characters (I even added these characters manually and it still didn't help)

Example of many many errors:

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: protected: virtual bool __cdecl clang::FrontendAction::shouldEraseOutputFiles(void)
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/anyany_llvm_pluginlib.dir/include/main.cpp.obj:(const anyany::plugin::`vftable')
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/anyany_llvm_pluginlib.dir/include/main.cpp.obj:(const clang::PluginASTAction::`vftable')
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/anyany_llvm_pluginlib.dir/include/main.cpp.obj:(const clang::ASTFrontendAction::`vftable')

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: virtual void __cdecl clang::FrontendAction::EndSourceFile(void)
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/anyany_llvm_pluginlib.dir/include/main.cpp.obj:(const anyany::plugin::`vftable')
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/anyany_llvm_pluginlib.dir/include/main.cpp.obj:(const clang::PluginASTAction::`vftable')
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/anyany_llvm_pluginlib.dir/include/main.cpp.obj:(const clang::ASTFrontendAction::`vftable')
```

(anyany_llvm_pluginlib is my cmake target)

CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.05)
project(anyany_llvm_plugin LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(anyany_llvm_pluginlib SHARED ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/main.cpp)

target_link_directories(anyany_llvm_pluginlib PUBLIC "WHERE_I_INSTALLED_LLVM/lib")

target_include_directories(anyany_llvm_pluginlib PUBLIC "WHERE_I_INSTALLED_LLVM/include")
target_link_libraries(anyany_llvm_pluginlib PUBLIC
clangAST
clangASTMatchers
clangBasic
clangFrontend
clangTooling
LLVMCore 
LLVMSupport 
LLVMOption 
LLVMMC 
LLVMBitWriter)
set_target_properties(anyany_llvm_pluginlib PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

I also tried this flag

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -undefined dynamic_lookup")
```

But it does not help =(

If i make library STATIC instead of SHARED, then all works.

The problem also solves if i remove this code required to add load plugin

```
static clang::FrontendPluginRegistry::Add<anyany::plugin> X = {
    "NAME", "DESCRIPTION"};
```